# Missing attributes in imported class in Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I declared a Java class -

```
class Beach {
    private String name, city;

    public Beach(String name, String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

I imported this into jython and tried to create an object -

```
import Beach
b = Beach("candolim", "goa")


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: java.lang.Object(): expected 0 args; got 2
```

Where is my two argument constructor?

**Edit:**

I follow these exact steps -

```
// Comment - Remove all files from directory to not create any confusion.
$ rm -rf *

$ vi Beach.java

class Beach {
private String name, city;

public Beach(String name, String city) {
  this.name = name;
  this.city = city;
 }
}

$ javac *.java
$ javap Beach

Compiled from "Beach.java"
class Beach {
  public Beach(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
}


$ jython
>>> import Beach
>>> b = Beach()
>>> dir(b)

['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', 'class', 'equals', 'getClass', 'hashCode', 'notify', 'notifyAll', 'toString', 'wait']
```

Comment: Probably in `Beach.Beach`, with your class.

Comment: Care to expand on that?

Comment: `Beach` is the module you've imported.

Comment: So Beach is a class in module Beach? import Beach.Beach does not work. `ImportError: No module named Beach
`

Comment: Of course not. Importing doesn't work like that in Python.

Comment: I've worked with Python. `from Beach import Beach` does not work. Neither does `import Beach` and `b = Beach.Beach()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the Java class shown in the question. I can reproduce the error.

beach.py:

```
import Beach

b = Beach("candolim", "goa")
print b.__class__
```

Beach.java alt. 1 (zero constructor arguments):

```
public class Beach {
  private String name, city;

  public Beach() {
  }
}
```

Output when using Beach.java alt. 1:

```
$ jython beach.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "beach.py", line 3, in <module>
    b = Beach("candolim", "goa")
TypeError: Beach(): expected 0 args; got 2
```

Beach.java alt. 2 (the class in the question; two arguments):

```
public class Beach {
private String name, city;

public Beach(String name, String city) {
  this.name = name;
  this.city = city;
 }
}
```

Output when using Beach.java alt. 2:

```
$ jython beach.py
<type 'Beach'>
```

---

**Edit**: something strange seems to be going on. Here is what happens when I try to follow the steps in the edited question:

```
$ rm *.class
$ cat Beach.java
public class Beach {
    private String name, city;

    public Beach(String name, String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }
}
$ javac Beach.java
$ javap Beach
Compiled from "Beach.java"
public class Beach {
  public Beach(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
}
$ jython
Jython 2.7b1 (default:ac42d59644e9, Feb 9 2013, 15:24:52)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_15
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Beach
>>> b = Beach()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Beach(): expected 2 args; got 0
>>>
```

Note that the `javap` output is different. Here it says `public class Beach`. In the question it is just `class Beach`.

Comment: Maybe OP didn't recompile the java file after adding arguments to the constructor?

Comment: Yes, that would be my guess.

Comment: @mzjn The problem was that Beach was not public as you said. Many thanks mzjn.

Comment: I wish that python would provide a descriptive error message instead of just instantiating a dummy object.